# PuTTY: how to properly emulate -t option

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty

On Linux the ssh command has a -t option whose man page reads:

> Force pseudo-tty allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary
>   screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful,
>   e.g. when implementing menu services. Multiple -t options force tty
>   allocate, even if ssh has no local tty.

I would like to use this same option with PuTTY on Windows. In particular,
I can see that PuTTY has a bunch of options under:

> Category -> Connection -> SSH -> TTY

and suspect it might be possible to achieve the same behavior via some
of the (NUMEROUS!) settings found on this screen. Anyone know how to
configure the following command:

```
ssh -t USER,PROJECT@shell.sourceforge.net create
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this? I too want to use -t so I can set a custom bash prompt without changing anything on the server side.

Comment: -t putty equivalent*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there would be any point for this option in PuTTY.

Normally, ssh on UNIX creates a TTY on the server side if and only if there is a TTY on the client side. Since you may use ssh both in a terminal, or from a script (where there's no terminal attached), this option makes sense on UNIX. But PuTTY only works with a terminal, so there's no point in forcing the TTY allocation on the server side, as it should always happen even without forcing.

Comment: Interesting answer. However this flag is necessary to access a shell on sourceforge it seems. So, there must be an option.